# Google Pay button not showing on Real Device using the pay Plugin Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-pay

I was trying to implement the *pay* plugin of Flutter. But the Google Pay button is not showing on a real device. It shows up in the Emulator.

This is the plugin I am using

```
pay: ^1.0.6
```

And this is my code for showing the payment buttons:

```
var _paymentItems = [
    PaymentItem(
      label: 'Total',
      amount: '99.99',
      status: PaymentItemStatus.final_price,
    )
  ];


GooglePayButton(
                    paymentConfigurationAsset: 'gpay.json',
                    paymentItems: _paymentItems,
                    width: 200,
                    height: 50,
                    style: GooglePayButtonStyle.white,
                    type: GooglePayButtonType.pay,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                    onPaymentResult: onGooglePayResult,
                    loadingIndicator: const Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
                  )
```

Is there any restriction for using **Google pay**?

I am from Bangladesh and I tried running on different devices, it's showing on none.

I will highly appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Soumik, add a value to the [`onError` parameter in the button](https://github.com/google-pay/flutter-plugin/blob/main/pay/lib/src/widgets/pay_button.dart#L59) to learn more about the reason for the error. You can also learn more about the [conditions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentsClient#isReadyToPay(com.google.android.gms.wallet.IsReadyToPayRequest)) under which isReadyToPay returns `true` and `false`. In this situation, as Omar points out, the country where you are operating from needs to be enabled for Google Pay.

Answer (score 1):

paying online with Google Pay is not available in Bangladesh.

https://support.google.com/pay/answer/9023773?hl=en#zippy=%2Cpay-online-or-in-apps